# if a set S is convex then $\left\langle x-y,z\right\rangle <\left\langle x-y,\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{2}\right\rangle $ for any z in the set

Tags: inequality, euclidean-geometry, convex-optimization, inner-products

let S be a convex set, and let $x\notin S;y,z\in S$.
such y is the closest to x in S.
prove:
$\left\langle x-y,z\right\rangle <\left\langle x-y,\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{2}\right\rangle $.
The inner product here is of course the euclidean one. and the distance is with the regular Euclidean distance.
I tried using Cauchy Schwartz, but it has not been successful.

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz could be helpful but it's not the inequality that springs to mind. There's another, more relevant inequality to do with projecting onto convex sets:$$\langle x - y, z - y \rangle \le 0,$$where $z \in S$ is arbitrary and $y \in S$ is the projection of $x$ onto $S$. Are you aware of this inequality?

Comment: @TheoBendit no? what is this?

Comment: I've heard of it attributed to Kolmogorov, but most of the time when I see it, people don't give it a name. Geometrically, it says that the line segment between a point $x$ and its projection $y$ makes an obtuse angle with a line segment between $y$ and any other point $z$ in the convex set. Or, if you like, the hyperplane orthogonal to $\overrightarrow{xy}$ lies tangent to $S$, separating $x$ from $S$.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that, if we just assume $y$ is some point in $S$ (not necessarily the projection of $S$) such that $\langle x - y, z - y \rangle \le 0$ for all $z \in S$, then $y$ must be the projection of $x$ onto $S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show that
$$
 \langle x-y,\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{2}\rangle - \langle x-y,z\rangle
= \langle x-y,\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{2}+y-z\rangle \\
= \frac 12\Vert x-y \Vert^2 + \langle x-y, y-z \rangle
$$
is strictly positive. It suffices to show that
$$ \tag {*}
\langle x-y, y-z \rangle \ge 0
$$
and that is true because $y$ is the closest point to $x$ in $S$: The function
$$
 [0, 1] \ni t \mapsto f(t) = \Vert x- (y+t(z-y))\Vert^2 \\= \Vert x-y \Vert^2 -2 t \langle x-y, z-y \rangle + t^2 \Vert z-y \Vert^2
$$
is minimal at $t=0$, therefore
$$
 f'(0) = -2  \langle x-y, z-y \rangle \ge 0
$$
and that proves $(*)$.

Comment: where you use the convexity of the set?

Comment: @thecorrectanswer In the second part: The point $y+t(z-y)$ is in $S$, so that its distance to $x$ is $\ge$ the distance from $y$ to $x$.

Comment: actually you proved the weak inequality, can you prove the strict one?

Comment: @thecorrectanswer: Note that $\frac 12\Vert x-y \Vert^2$ is strictly positive, so this does prove the strict inequality.

Comment: sorry I fail to understand the shift from inner product to norm, can you please detail more?

Comment: @thecorrectanswer: In an inner produce space, the norm is defined via $\Vert x \Vert^2 = \langle x, x \rangle$.

Comment: yeah I know this , how you switched to $\Vert x-y \Vert^2 -2 t \langle x-y, z-y \rangle + t^2 \Vert z-y \Vert^2$

Comment: @thecorrectanswer: $\Vert a-b\Vert^2 = \langle a-b, a-b \rangle = \langle a, a \rangle -2 \langle a, b \rangle + \langle b, b \rangle  = \Vert a \Vert^2 - 2 \langle a, b \rangle + \Vert b \Vert^2 $

Comment: sorry me, this $\langle x-y, y-z \rangle \ge 0$ to that $[0, 1] \ni t \mapsto f(t) = \Vert x- (y+t(z-y))\Vert^2 \\$

Answer (score 1):

Here is geometric proof.  Let $t={1\over 2}(x+y).$ (We shall only use that
$t$ is strictly between $x$ and $y$ on the line segment $xy.$) Let $B$ be the closed ball of radius
|x-y| and center $x.$  Observe that $S\cap B=\{y\}.$ Let $H$ be the hyperplane through
$y$ with normal $x-y.$ If $z$ were on the same side of $H$ as $t,$ then the line segment $yz$
would intersect $B$ at points other than $y,$ a contradiction. Thus, $z$ is on $H$ or on the opposite
side from $t.$ Therefore, $\langle x-y,t-z\rangle\gt 0.$ In other words,
$$\left\langle x-y,z\right\rangle <\left\langle x-y,t\right\rangle.$$